# Moving a div by radio buttons with math.random without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I’m relatively new to JavaScript and have been reading up on it. I don’t know JQuery yet and plan to do that next. I’m trying to probably figure something thats simple out.

What I want to do is - I have 3 radio buttons, I have named them ‘Small Jump’, ‘Medium Jump’ and ‘Big Jump’. I want a 30x30 div to move across the screen at each click on the radio button. And I want to use math.random that way the div is not just going to float to the same area again if I re-click the ‘radio’ button.

How can I do this? I have mouseover feature that I want, but the radio buttons do NOT move the div.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
    <html>
<head>

<style>
div.a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
}
</style>


<body>
<h3>Click</h3>
Small Jump <input type="radio" id="smallRadio" name="speed"><br>
Medium Jump: <input type="radio" id="mediumRadio" name="speed"><br>
Big Jump: <input type="radio" id="largeRadio" name="speed"><br>

<div class='a' id="mainDiv" onmouseover=" move();"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

console.log("hello");

function move() {
    var redBox = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    var position = parseInt(redBox.style.left);
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("speed");
    if (radios[0].checked) {
        console.log('small button checked');
    }
    console.log(radios);
    position = position || 0;
    redBox.style.left = position + 50 + "px";
}
       function showStyle() {
     var id = document.getElementById("a");
     var str = "";


     // var chosenValue = Math.random() * 10; 
     str = str + "position: " + id.style.position + ";";
     str += "<br>top: " + id.style.top;
     str += "<br>left: " + id.style.left;
     str += "<br>width: " + id.style.width;
     str += "<br>height: " + id.style.height;
     document.getElementById("smallRadio").innerHTML = str;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to move the DIV by using radio-buttons. To which direction? And why not use `<button>` elements?

Comment: I never thought of using <button> elements.

I mean I want the DIV to move using radio-buttons in ANY direction using math-random. It don't matter. Each 3 are different, thats what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Might not be a good option after all :)

Comment: You want the DIV to move when the mouse goes over it right?

Comment: Oh?  I tried earlier to use JQuery, but got all messy quick, couldn't understand what was going on then. So decided pure Javascript would make my life easier.

Comment: There are some errors in your code, but I'll make a example

Comment: Yes, correct. The radio button is highlighted, then the mouse moves over it. Three different movements, one a small jump, one a medium, and a large jump. I believe I'm overcomplicating this too much.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You're welcome, hope this helps. You might want to check http://api.jquery.com for references of the functions and methods used in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example with comments explaining what it does. Is uses jQuery (sorry) since that has a far better (and easier) way of doing JavaScript things for all browsers :)

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){

  // Initiate mouseover function when page is loaded
  
  $('#mainDiv').mouseover(function(){
      // What to do when mouse hovers over #mainDiv:
    
      // Get step size (value) from the radio-input named 'speed' that is checked :
      var stepSize = parseInt( $('input[type=radio][name=speed]:checked').val() );

      // Get the current position:
      var pos = $( this ).position();
      var left = parseInt( pos.left );
      var top = parseInt( pos.top );
    
      // Calculate new positions
      var new_left = left + stepSize;
      var new_top = top + stepSize;
    
      // Change the element's CSS to the new position(s)
      $( this ).css('left', new_left + 'px' );
      $( this ).css('top', new_top + 'px' );
  });

});
```

```css
div.a {
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Choose step size:</h3>
1 px <input type="radio" id="smallRadio" name="speed" value="1" checked="checked"><br>
10 px <input type="radio" id="mediumRadio" name="speed" value="10"><br>
100 px <input type="radio" id="largeRadio" name="speed" value="100"><br>

<div class='a' id="mainDiv" onmouseover=" move();"></div>
```

Comment: The `parseInt()` function is used to make sure JavaScript treat these values as integers, and not as strings. (Which would cause the addition to create a left value of '81' -> '811' -> '8111' etc. )

Answer (score 0):

I created [a fiddle with a potential solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bergonom/t5xdtruL/6/):

Basically I removed the event handler from the html:

```
<h3>Click</h3>
Small Jump <input type="radio" id="smallRadio" name="speed"><br>
Medium Jump: <input type="radio" id="mediumRadio" name="speed"><br>
Big Jump: <input type="radio" id="largeRadio" name="speed"><br>

<div class='a' id="mainDiv"></div>
```

And moved it to the JS:

```
element = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    moveBox();
});

function moveBox() {
    var redBox = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    var position = parseInt(redBox.style.left);
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("speed");
    if (radios[0].checked) {
        console.log('small button checked');
    }

    position = position || 0;
    redBox.style.left = position + 50 + "px";
}
```

I didn't add the random movements because I didn't know what you meant and figured it shouldn't be too hard to add that part of it.